# Hibernate doesn't insert values into EmbeddedId with mappings

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a **ClassA** entity, which contains set of ClassB entities.

```
public class ClassA {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "classA")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REFRESH, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Set<ClassB> classB = new HashSet<>();

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void setClassA() {
        if (nonNull(this.classB)) {
            this.classB.forEach(b -> b.setA(this));
        }
    }
}
```

**ClassB** entity has composite key, which points to two other entities' ids.

```
@Embeddable
public class ClassBId implements Serializable {
    private String cId;
    private Long aId;
}
```

```
public class ClassB {

    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "c", column = @Column(name = "c_id")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "a", column = @Column(name = "a_id"))
    })
    @EmbeddedId
    private ClassBId id;

    @OneToOne
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REFRESH, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @MapsId("cId")
    private ClassC classC;
    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REFRESH, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @MapsId("aId")
    private ClassA classA;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private void setEmbeddedId() {
        id.setCId(c.getId());
        id.setAId(a.getId());
    }
}
```

When I save my **ClassA** entity and CrudRepository returns me a result, everything is nicely filled in but that **embedded id remains null**, with or without setting id manually in pre-operation method.

What kind of join or mapping am I missing so on save or update I can not only have ClassC and ClassA inside of ClassB entity (which takes place already) but also somehow have that composite key consisting of PKs of ClassA and ClassC automagically filled in?

Comment: You aren't showing how you are checking the result, the transaction settings or how and when the IDs for A and C are set. JPA should automatically set the embedded id properties based on the relationship values, but only on the managed entity instance and likely (provider can control this) when the transaction commits or is flushed. So how you save your entity and return it matters (JPA merge has different behavior than jpa persist).

Comment: I just call saveAndFlush on my simple ClassA repository, which extends JpaRepository<ClassA, Long>. I wrote few integration tests and while debugging the reason I don't get expected results after save I could see that returned entity after insert has all the fields set, but that composite key has null fields.

Comment: Regarding ID generation:
ClassA

`@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = a_SEQ, strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = a_SEQ, sequenceName = a_SEQ, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;`

Comment: Show what you mean as it is a common mistake to pass in an instance to save and just assume that your object passed in becomes managed - use the instance it returns, not the one you gave it to check for generated values after the flush/commit. Also show the references are set, and how A and C are managed in the context. As the answer states below states you have, do you initialize the embedded object? I'd have expected an NPE in your callbacks if you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assign the id to at least an empty object for this to work:

```
@EmbeddedId
private ClassBId id = new ClassBId();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did add that and now when calling repository.save(classA) and then getting it from db I can see my embeddedId with null fields set. 
I was expecting that hibernate would set those fields automatically on save.

Comment: I could possibly set cId because I know that value but when it comes to ClassA id it's being generated via sequence, so before inserting it I do not know it. It seems like I would have to save that Set<ClassB> classB manually after saving ClassA, which makes no sense.

Comment: I don't know if Hibernate should mess with the object here, but note that you can also just define the `ClassC` and `ClassA` associations in the `ClassBId`, then you won't have that problem.